# How would I convert this code to something shorter? Potentially through an Array?

Tags: excel, vba

I have working code for my need, however now that I have learned this much, I want to go back and make it more streamlined.

I have attempted arrays, but apparently do not understand them..

```
Sub addGreenx(newbook)
Set newbook = ActiveWorkbook

 myrow = 1
 mycolumn = "M"
 For Each r In Intersect(newbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("AQ:AQ"),     newbook.Sheets("Sheet1").UsedRange)
If InStr(r, "Green") And InStr(r, "red") = 0 Then
    newbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range(mycolumn + Mid(Str(myrow), 2)) = "X"
End If
myrow = myrow + 1
Next r

End Sub

Sub addBluex(newbook)
Set newbook = ActiveWorkbook

myrow = 1
mycolumn = "O"
For Each r In Intersect(newbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("AQ:AQ"),     newbook.Sheets("Sheet1").UsedRange)
If InStr(r, "Blue") And InStr(r, "Red") = 0 Then
    newbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range(mycolumn + Mid(Str(myrow), 2)) = "X"
End If
myrow = myrow + 1
Next r

End Sub

Sub addTealx(newboox)

Set newbook = ActiveWorkbook
myrow = 1
mycolumn = "O"
For Each r In Intersect(newbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("AQ:AQ"), newbook.Sheets("Sheet1").UsedRange)
If InStr(r, "Teal") And InStr(r, "Red") = 0 Then
    newbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range(mycolumn + Mid(Str(myrow), 2)) = "X"
End If
myrow = myrow + 1
Next r

End Sub
```

This can be made shorter I'm sure, the item in "mycolumn" may have both blue and green, or just one or the other, however if it is blue the x goes in one column, if green in another, and if both in both.

Comment: A somehow digressive tip: use indentation in your code, it makes it much more readable than what you posted

Comment: How can I copy and paste code in here with the indents? in my code it is indented, but when I paste here and indent to show as code I just didn't take the time to indent it all as is in program

Comment: That is weird, when I copy code from standard VBA Excel editor it translates the indentation here.

Answer (score 1):

If you always run these together then you only need a single loop and inside that loop test for each condition.

```
Sub CheckForColors()
    Dim r As Range, sht As Worksheet, v

    Set sht = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    For Each r In Intersect(sht.Range("AQ:AQ"), sht.UsedRange)
        v = r.Value
        If InStr(v, "Red") = 0 Then
            If InStr(v, "Green") > 0 Then r.EntireRow.columns("M").Value = "x"
            If InStr(v, "Blue") > 0 Or InStr(v, "Teal") > 0 Then _
                             r.EntireRow.columns("O").Value = "x"
        End If
    Next r

End Sub
```